# jQuery - Better solution for removing <dt> and <dd>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML source:

```
<dl class="plain inlineDataList userStats">
    <dt><a href="someUrl">Test1</a></dt>
    <dd>2.710</dd>

    <dt><a href="anotherUrl">Test2</a></dt>
    <dd>408</dd>

    <dt>Test3</dt>
    <dd>2.693</dd>
</dl>
```

Now I am trying to remove the last two. It should look like that in the end:

```
<dl class="plain inlineDataList userStats">
    <dt><a href="someUrl">Test1</a></dt>
    <dd>2.710</dd>

    <dt><a href="anotherUrl">Test2</a></dt>
    <dd>408</dd>
</dl>
```

The last *dt* and *dd* should be deleted/removed. My current idea is:

```
$('dl.plain.userStats > dd:last-child').remove();
$('dl.plain.userStats > dt:last-child').remove();
```

This works but I think there are better solutions, also I think I am understanding *last-child* wrong as it actually removes the last element, it doesn't matter what it is.

When I do *$('dl.plain.userStats > bla:last-child').remove();* it also works.
Do you have any better solutions to do that or  is that maybe even ok?

Thanks

Comment: I'd use `:last` or `.last()` rather than `:last-child`. As in `$('dl.plain.userStats > dd').last().remove();`

Comment: I think that you have the right concept for last child, but possibly the > selector is messing it up. Technically you dont need it for this and it may be making your selector function select the last child that is a direct descendant of the parent no matter what it is.

Comment: You have code that does what you want, and you are asking for a “better way”, without presenting any criteria. Besides, the code with `bla:` does *not* work; you must have misinterpreted something.

Answer (score 2):

> I think I am understanding last-child wrong as it actually removes the
>   last element, it doesn't matter what it is.

No.

`$('dl.plain.userStats > dd:last-child')` will remove *only last*  `dd`  which is  **also** the last child  of `dl.plain.userStats`.

> $('dl.plain.userStats > bla:last-child').remove(); it also works.

No.

`$('dl.plain.userStats > bla:last-child').remove();`

will *not* remove last `dt` unless your  `bla` is `dt`

Consider this example :  http://jsbin.com/huqeketiya/1/edit

```
  <a>
  <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>
   <div>4</div>
   <span>5</span>
  </a>
```

This code :

```
 $("div:last-child" ).css('background-color','red')
```

Will not paint anything !

as i said : it looks for a  `div` which is **also** last child , so there is no result here

Comment: _"will remove only a dd which is the last one among dd's"_ - that is not correct. `:last-child` selects only elements that are the last child of their parent _regardless of type,_ not the last of similarly typed elements. (As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chwh013e/).) The OP's code works because it removes the dd element first, so then when it gets to `dt:last-child` the dt actually is the last child of its parent.

Comment: @nnnnnn that is partlly correct. i'll edit. see this http://jsbin.com/hamacopuci/2/edit , the last one is not painted in red and still it is the last child !